# How to count in SQL all fields with null values in one record?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to count all fields with null values for specific record excluding PrimaryKey column?

```
Example:

ID  Name    Age    City     Zip

1   Alex    32     Miami    NULL
2   NULL    24     NULL     NULL
```

As output I need to get 1 and 3. Without explicitly specifying column names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Age int,
  City varchar(10),
  Zip varchar(10)
)  

insert into @T values 
(1, 'Alex', 32, 'Miami', NULL),
(2,  NULL,  24,  NULL,   NULL)

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select ID,
       (
          select *
          from @T as T2
          where T1.ID = T2.ID
          for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type 
       ).value('count(/row/*[@ns:nil = "true"])', 'int') as NullCount
from @T as T1
```

Result:

```
ID          NullCount
----------- -----------
1           1
2           3
```

**Update:**

Here is a better version. Thanks to [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith).

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select ID,
       (
          select T1.*
          for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type 
       ).value('count(/row/*[@ns:nil = "true"])', 'int') as NullCount
from @T as T1
```

**Update:**

And with a bit faster XQuery expression.

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select ID,
       (
          select T1.*
          for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type 
       ).value('count(//*/@ns:nil)', 'int') as NullCount
from @T as T1
```

Comment: [I think you can improve the sub query here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14870/3690)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yes of course. No need to have the table one more time in there.

Comment: +1 This worked wonders.  Only had 1.1k rows to check for.  FYI this also evaluates the textual version of NULL.  This got me started, but http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null/14870#14870 finished me off

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN City IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN Zip  IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM YourTable
```

If you do not want explicit column names in query, welcome to dynamic querying

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'  CASE WHEN '+QUOTENAME(c.name)+N' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +'
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE 
    c.is_nullable = 1
AND t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')

SET @sql = N'SELECT id, '+@sql +N'+0 AS Cnt FROM [YourTableName]'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I asked without specifying column names !?!

Comment: @Martin: I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
select count (id) 
where ( isnull(Name,"") = "" or isnull(City,"") = "" or isnull(Zip,"") = "" )
```

Not a smart solution, but it should do the work.

Comment: I asked without specifying column names !?!

Comment: I hope the `Group By` - statement to extend my sample isn't the problem for you, if so then >:o

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tempSQL nvarchar(max)
SET @tempSQL = N'SELECT '

SELECT @tempSQL = @tempSQL + 'sum(case when ' + cols.name + ' is null then 1 else 0 end) "Null Values for ' + cols.name + '",
            sum(case when ' + cols.name + ' is null then 0 else 1 end) "Non-Null Values for ' + cols.name + '",' FROM sys.columns cols WHERE cols.object_id = object_id('TABLE1');

SET @tempSQL = SUBSTRING(@tempSQL, 1, LEN(@tempSQL) - 1) + ' FROM TABLE1;'

EXEC sp_executesql @tempSQL
```