# Find all records which contain both null and empty columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL is not really my strong point, so please excuse my ignorance.

This query returns all records which contain null values

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
SELECT *
FROM   Analytics
WHERE  (SELECT Analytics.*
        FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
        ).value('count(//*[local-name() != "colToIgnore"]/@ns:nil)', 'int') > 0
```

Source: [Find All Rows With Null Value(s) in Any Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488859/find-all-rows-with-null-values-in-any-column)

The above query returns a list of records which have null values. How do I modify this query to return records which contains both null or empty columns.

Comment: What specific database? Add a tag for it.

Comment: MSSQL actually, editing it

Comment: And more important, are you really a Navy Seal? And if so, what do SQL Server databases have to do with MP5s? Shouldn't you be drilling right about now?  :)

Comment: Some of the seals do get to work on SQL Server databases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
SELECT *
FROM   Analytics
WHERE  (SELECT Analytics.*
        FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
        ).value('count(//*[local-name() != "colToIgnore"]/@ns:nil)', 'int') > 0
        OR
        (SELECT Analytics.*
        FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
        ).value('count(//*[text()=""])', 'int') > 0
```