# How to find all rows with a NULL value in any column using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are many *slightly similar* questions, but none solve precisely this problem.  "[Find All Rows With Null Value(s) in Any Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488859/find-all-rows-with-null-values-in-any-column)" is the closest one I could find and offers an answer for SQL Server, but I'm looking for a way to do this in PostgreSQL.

How can I select only the rows that have NULL values in *any* column?

I can get all the column names easily enough:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'A';
```

but it's unclear how to check multiple column names for NULL values.  Obviously this won't work:

```
select* from A where (
  select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'A';
) IS NULL;
```

And [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgres+check+multiple+columns+for+null+values&oq=postgres+check+multiple+columns+for+null+values&aqs=chrome..69i57.22589j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=postgres+SQL+check+multiple+columns+for+null+values) has not turned up anything useful.

Comment: There is another previous answer, that's much closer (actually answers your question - same solution that @Marth has posted)): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026085/939860

Comment: That does appear to be similar (although it's hard to understand because the questioner never poses a simple form of the question directly) but it's a bit different because it's about *specific* columns being NOT NULL rather than *any* columns being NOT NULL.  Nonetheless it is very useful to know that question is there. Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `NOT(<table> IS NOT NULL)`.

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparison.html) :

> If the expression is row-valued, then IS NULL is true when the row
> expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, while
> IS NOT NULL is true when the row expression itself is non-null and all
> the row's fields are non-null.

So given table `t`,

```
SELECT * FROM t;
┌────────┬────────┐
│   f1   │   f2   │
├────────┼────────┤
│ (null) │      1 │
│      2 │ (null) │
│ (null) │ (null) │
│      3 │      4 │
└────────┴────────┘
(4 rows)
```

here are all the possible variants:

```
SELECT * FROM t             SELECT * FROM t           
WHERE (t IS NULL);          WHERE (t IS NOT NULL);    
┌────────┬────────┐         ┌────────┬────────┐       
│   f1   │   f2   │         │   f1   │   f2   │       
├────────┼────────┤         ├────────┼────────┤       
│ (null) │ (null) │         │      3 │      4 │       
└────────┴────────┘         └────────┴────────┘       
(1 row)                     (1 rows)                  
                                                      
                                                      

SELECT * FROM t             SELECT * FROM t           
WHERE NOT (t IS NULL);      WHERE NOT (t IS NOT NULL);
┌────────┬────────┐         ┌────────┬────────┐       
│   f1   │   f2   │         │   f1   │   f2   │       
├────────┼────────┤         ├────────┼────────┤       
│ (null) │      1 │         │ (null) │      1 │       
│      2 │ (null) │         │      2 │ (null) │       
│      3 │      4 │         │ (null) │ (null) │       
└────────┴────────┘         └────────┴────────┘       
(3 rows)                    (3 rows)
```

Comment: I was thinking about `row_to_json()` but this is much better

Comment: Of course its pg 8.2 so redshift dont got it... oh well have to list all my columns...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution which **might** be of use in some edge cases could be the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3DWDB3QB)):

### Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
  f1 INT,
  f2 INT,
  f3 TEXT,
  f4 INT,
  f5 TEXT
  --
  -- arbitrary number of fields...
  --
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
(null, 1, 'blah', 5, 'xxx'),
(2, null, 'yyy', 6, 'wwww'),
(null, null, 'ggg', 99, 'wwww'), 
(3, 4, 'yyy', 17, 'yuoyo');  -- no NULLs
```

### Row SQL:

First, we run:

```
SELECT ROW(t) FROM t;
```

Result:

```
row
("(,1,blah,5,xxx)")
("(2,,yyy,6,wwww)")
("(,,ggg,99,wwww)")
("(3,4,yyy,17,yuoyo)")
```

Hmmm... a bit messy, so now we run:

```
SELECT ROW(t.*) FROM t;
```

Result:

```
row
(,1,blah,5,xxx)
(2,,yyy,6,wwww)
(,,ggg,99,wwww)
(3,4,yyy,17,yuoyo)
```

OK, this is bit tidier - so, now , the solution that I'm proposing. Please bear in mind that I'm not suggesting that it is better than the accepted answer (see performance analysis below). What I **am** suggesting is that  my solution **might** be of use in some tricky edge cases.

So, we run:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ROW(t.*)::TEXT FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE row ~ '^\(,|,,|,\)';
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^` - the caret character is an [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) - it means the start of the string.
- `\` - is the escape character.
- `(` - the character being escaped. It's a [metacharacter](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) (i.e. special meaning in regexes) - normally for [`capturing groups`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), but being escaped, it's now a literal bracket.
- `,` - a literal comma.
- `|` - the pipe character - [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) in regexes - i.e. `OR` - taken altogether, `^\(,|,,` means either `(,` OR `,,`.
- `|,\)` - wrapping it up, the final OR and then matching `,)`.

So, the regex matches **either** `(,` OR `,,` OR `,)`. Basically, this pulls out any row where there is a `NULL` **either** at the beginning of the row string, OR in the middle OR at the end of the string.

- ** a word of warning, this regex could fail if you have "weird" text strings with random characters - it is conceivable that you may get one of the combinations above - *caveat emptor*!

Result:

```
row
(,1,blah,5,xxx)  -- matches (,
(2,,yyy,6,wwww)  -- matches ,,
(,,ggg,99,wwww)  -- matches both (, and ,,
--
-- Note that the row with no NULLs has been excluded, as desired
--
```

### Performance analysis:

Queries should always be checked for performance, so we run:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ROW(t.*)::TEXT FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE row ~ '^\(,|,,|,\)';
```

Result (details snipped, see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3DWDB3QB)):

```
Planning Time: 0.038 ms
Execution Time: 0.062 ms
```

and the same for `SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT (t IS NOT NULL);`:

```
Planning Time: 0.039 ms
Execution Time: 0.018 ms
```

So, we can see that the accepted answer takes ~ 30% of the time that this regex solution does. Regexes are very powerful, but with greater power comes greater complexity - apply regexes with caution! A great site to learn about them is to be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

After getting the list of column and table, you can use `LOOP` and `EXECUTE` to run them one by one.

This wouldn't give you the answer in table form, but at least you can eyeball it via the `RAISE NOTICE`s, as for my use case, it's only part of a maintenance/patching work.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
    id_columns TEXT;
    id_column_tables TEXT;
    null_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR id_columns, id_column_tables IN (
        SELECT column_name, table_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name = 'A' 
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I WHERE %I is null',
            id_column_tables,
            id_columns
        ) INTO null_count;
        
        IF null_count > 0 then
            RAISE NOTICE 'Column: % in TABLE: % - Null Count: %', id_columns, id_column_tables, null_count;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: This looks really interesting but all I ever get is `Query 1 OK: DO`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but the RAISE NOTICE seems to only print stuff when using a GUI like PgAdmin. I tried the query myself using psql and yeah, it didn't work