# Django filter for all items which contain at least one null value

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

An answer elsewhere on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035052/2323727) provides the Postgresql `NOT(<table> IS NOT NULL)` query as an option to find all rows in a table containing one or more null values. How would one apply this query in the Django ORM without writing raw SQL? Or is this a case where raw SQL is required?

I couldn't find an example of such as query in the [latest Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/).

For reference, the example shown in the linked answer is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
┌────────┬────────┐
│   f1   │   f2   │
├────────┼────────┤
│ (null) │      1 │
│      2 │ (null) │
│ (null) │ (null) │
│      3 │      4 │
└────────┴────────┘
(4 rows)

SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT (t IS NOT NULL);
┌────────┬────────┐
│   f1   │   f2   │
├────────┼────────┤
│ (null) │      1 │
│      2 │ (null) │
│ (null) │ (null) │
└────────┴────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: If there are not many fields in your model, you could create something like this  `YourModel.objects.filter(Q(Q(field1__isnull=True) | Q(field_2__isnull=True)) `

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev The reason why I haven't taken that route is twofold: 1. the model is loaded dynamically, so the fields will be different every time (not insurmountable, but inconvenient), and 2. I expect such a query would be slower than the one suggested in the linked answer. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can get model's current fields from `self.model._meta.fields`. And than entire query will look as follow: 
`YourModel.objects.filter(**{'{0}__isnull'.format(field.name): True for field in self.model._meta.fields})`

Comment: Thanks again for the response. The trouble with this option is that the filter() call combines the lookup parameters using SQL AND instead of OR. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter. 

So the query would only match items where all values are null, instead of where any value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to add additional WHERE clauses to your query

```
Model.objects.extra(where=['NOT (%s IS NOT NULL)'], params=[Model._meta.db_table])
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this. What I found was that by adding the extra() call, the query generated works (appeding .query to the end of the call) perfectly if I run it on the DB by hand, but for some reason it does not return any results when run by Django. I'm still investigating that issue and will report back once solved.

Comment: So this seems to work:

Model.objects.all().extra(where=['NOT (' + Model._meta.db_table + ' IS NOT NULL)'])

For some reason passing the table name as a params argument fails.