# How to check for null values in a row?

Tags: postgresql

I want the rows in which there is at least one column with a null value. I've tried to use a row expression like:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE <table> IS NULL
```

But it does not work. Is my query incorrect or?

PS I am using version 13.4

Comment: `FROM <table>` What is '<table>' ? please don't invent meta-syntax. Post real code.

Comment: @wildplasser because I need the expression to work for any table. I am making an API to accept database connections and do basic, automated analyses on them. One of which is testing for incomplete rows. In this case, an incomplete row would be one containing null values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all rows with a NULL value in any column using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034847/how-to-find-all-rows-with-a-null-value-in-any-column-using-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the table alias in the WHERE clause. The condition `where the_table is not null` would return the rows where **all** columns are not null.

The opposite of that (where at least one column is null) can be achieved by negating the expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where not (the_table is not null);
```

Looks a bit strange, but it's not the same as `the_table is null` - which is never true, as the reference to the table (alias) refers to an existing row. And if a row exists the the "whole row" can't be null.

This:

```
with the_table (col1, col2, col3) as (
values 
  (1,null,null),
  (null,2,null), 
  (null,3,4),
  (5,6,7)
  
) 
select *
from the_table 
where not (the_table is not null);
```

returns:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+-----
   1 |      |     
     |    2 |     
     |    3 |    4
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if the value is not null, you use the `IS NOT NULL` operator

`value IS NOT NULL`

The expression returns true if the value is NULL or false if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention your column name in the search.

SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> IS NULL;

For more than one columns:

SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column1_name> IS NULL OR <column2_name> IS NULL;