# Where is using a table name as a "row value" documented?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT (table IS NOT NULL);
```

finds all the rows in `table` that have a `null` value in any column. The logic is clear (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035052/1498178)), but want to understand this syntax. A statement in an answer says "*[the reference to the table (alias) refers to an existing row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69087309/1498178)*" and the [PostgreSQL `SELECT` documentation's `WHERE` section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WHERE) states that "*a row satisfies the condition if it returns true when the actual **row values** are substituted for any variable references*" (emphasis mine). A [keyword search on "row values"](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?q=row%20value) yielded references to the [4.2 Value Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html) page, but I couldn't find an answer there either (unless I overlooked something).

---

**update**: After Laurenz Albe pointed out that the `ROW` [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) is used behind the scenes, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026085/1498178) is also relevant.
It shows that

```
CHECK (NOT (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NULL)
```

is (functionally) the same as

```
CHECK (NOT ROW(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NULL)
```

Neither the [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) docs nor the pages referenced there mention this usage anywhere, so I guess this form only spread by word of mouth. (Or I missed it, and should get better at reading comprehension.)

Comment: For those like me who have never come across `IS [NOT] NULL` on a complete row, here is a fiddle that may help understand what it does: https://dbfiddle.uk/OlcL1Gvy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical term in PostgreSQL is a “whole-row reference”, and it doesn't seem to be documented except in the source code. By using the table name as a column, you get a composite value consisting of all columns.

You can see

```
SELECT tab FROM tab;
```

as being the same as

```
SELECT ROW(tab.*) FROM tab;
```

Comment: So this behavior is specific to PostgreSQL and not in the SQL standard - did I get that right? (Also, would you mind linking to the source? Just curiuos, thanks!)

Comment: Yes, this is non-standard behavior (as is the use of `*` inside a `ROW()` constructor). I could not find a single good place in the source to quote. It is all over.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034847/how-to-find-all-rows-with-a-null-value-in-any-column-using-postgresql/31035052#31035052) could be (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TPWywkXk)):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ROW(t.*)::TEXT FROM t
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE row ~ '\(,|,,|,\)';
```

Now, it uses a regex and these can be expensive - as we can see from the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) <My_Query>' - my regex query is about 3 times as expensive as

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE NOT (t IS NOT NULL);
```

I also included a couple of other variants of using the `ROW` keyword in the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the details and for taking the time to showing all these different scenarios! Would you consider moving your answer to the thread that you (and I also) linked? The reason I'm asking is that it is more relevant there (and I would upvote there right away), but I don't want to upvote it here because it doesn't answer my question. I would also recommend posting the entire fiddle as well, in case link rot sets in at one point.

Comment: @toraritte - I've done as you suggested. I've been careful to make it clear that I'm not saying that my answer is better than the accepted one, just that it might be useful in edge cases - I'm at pains also to point out that regexes incur a performance penalty. Here's the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196354/470530) for my answer. If you spot any flaws, I'd be grateful if you could point them out. I'll delete this answer in a few days - thanks for your input!