# Sum Listagg in a query

Tags: oracle, sum, listagg

I am trying to sum the values from the listagg query i made.

Expected result should be like this

```
SELECT LEGAL_ENTITY_ID, SUM(0 + 0 + 0 + 1) as Grandtotals
FROM V_VBA_DDCR_MAIN WHERE LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=6012346 AND ROWNUM=1
GROUP BY LEGAL_ENTITY_ID

 |      LEGAL_ENTITY_ID | GRANDTOTALS 
1|    6012346           | 1
```

My listagg goes like this

```
SELECT LISTAGG(NVL2(FLDNM,0,1) , '+ ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FLDNM) FROM LE_MERGE_DDC_MAPPING
```

the purpose of this query is to count the number of null fields in a row. I created a table containing the list of fields that needs to be checked for null values.

Result :

```
    fld1 + fld2 + fld3 + fld4
=
        0 + 0 + 0 + 1
```

So I wrote my query like this:

```
SELECT LEGAL_ENTITY_ID, SUM(SELECT LISTAGG(NVL2(FLDNM,0,1) , '+ ') WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY FLDNM) FROM LE_MERGE_DDC_MAPPING) as Grandtotals
FROM V_VBA_DDCR_MAIN WHERE LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=6000132
GROUP BY LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
```

However, I am getting an error ORA-00936: missing expression.
I am not sure if Oracle allows you to do a sum of the listagg function.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using listagg?  you should probably just `SUM(NVL2(FLDNM,0,1))`

Comment: `listagg` creates a string, not an expression that `sum()` can interpret. A sum of a string doesn't make any sense (even if it happens to be a string value that can be implicitly converted to a single number - summing one number doesn't make much sense either). If your first query does what you want, why are you looking at `listagg` at all? What are you trying to achieve? (And what is the `rownum` supposed to be doing - your aggregate will only return one row anyway. And why is it tagged with both MySQL and Oracle - which are you using?)

Comment: @Ricado Arnold. used listagg to get the fields that got null values based on the list of important fields that needs to be checked. So i created a table  containing the list of all the fields needed to be checked since we have a total of 300++ fields and only need to check 100 fields.

Comment: @Alexpoole ohh now i know. I was using rownum because the view im using got lots of duplicate records with the same info. 1st row is already okay for me.

Comment: so I wanted to shorten this expression
`NVL2(FLD1,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD2,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD3,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD4,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD5,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD6,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD7,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD8,0,1) + 
NVL2(FLD..n,0,1)`

Comment: So you want to get the list of fields to check dynamically from the other table? Is that list actually going to change or are you just trying to save some typing while creating this query? All you'll really do is make it more complicated. (Your `listagg` will always evaluate to `0+ 0+ 0+ ....` anyway incidentally).

Comment: Yes. Wanted to check the list of fields, because of the business rules given. its a bit complex because for one legal entity can have only 40 fields to check while other legal entity might need 100++ fields to check if null or not. That's why i thought of thinking listagg instead

this btw is related to the same issue most user are experiencing - **How to count in SQL all fields with null values in one record?** - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079037/how-to-count-in-sql-all-fields-with-null-values-in-one-record)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT LISTAGG(NVL2(FLDNM,0,1) , '+ ')...` query will always get string result `'0+ 0+ 0+ ...'`, unless you have rows in `LE_MERGE_DDC_MAPPING` which are null. That value is nothing to do with the `V_VBA_DDCR_MAIN` table. You could generate a string that contains the expressions:

```
SELECT LISTAGG('NVL2(' || FLDNM || ' ,0,1)' , '+ ') ...
```

But that would just leave you with a *string* containing `'NVL2(fld1 ,0,1)+ NVL2(fld2 ,0,1)+ ...'`. You can't sum a string, and `sum()` can't evaluate a string as an expression. You would need to generate a dynamic SQL statement based on that string.

There is a way to do that with XML, which isn't entirely intuitive. You can use the `dbms_xmlgen` package to create an XML document (as a CLOB) which contains a node with the NVL2 result from your actual target table:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select nvl2(' || fldnm || ',0,1) from v_vba_ddcr_main where legal_entity_id=6012346')
from le_merge_ddc_mapping map;
```

I won't show the generated XML here. You can then query that to get the individual values out:

```
select xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/*/text()'
  passing xmltype(
    dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select nvl2(' || fldnm || ',0,1) from v_vba_ddcr_main where Legal_Entity_Id=6012346')
  ) 
  returning content)
from le_merge_ddc_mapping;
```

And you can them sum those:

```
select sum(to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/*/text()'
  passing xmltype(
    dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select nvl2(' || fldnm || ',0,1) from v_vba_ddcr_main where legal_entity_id=6012346')
  )
  returning content))) as grandtotals
from le_merge_ddc_mapping;
```

You've suggested there is a link between the tables, to determine which fields are included, so you'd need to add that. And you've said there are duplicates, which you'd need to handle - preferably by eliminating them from your view, but with a subquery if necessary. This can be a starting point for you to develop from though.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll try the suggested queries above and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `LISTAGG` at all?

```
SELECT LEGAL_ENTITY_ID,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM   LE_MERGE_DDC_MAPPING
         WHERE  FLDNM IS NULL
       ) as Grandtotals
FROM   V_VBA_DDCR_MAIN
WHERE  LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=6000132;
```

*(Since you are filtering on a single `LEGAL_ENTITY_ID` you don't need the final `GROUP BY`)*

Are you sure there shouldn't be some sort of join condition between the two tables?