# check for null values in all columns of a table using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with more than 15 columns. 2 of of them are of the type varchar, and most of them of type int and float.

I am new to SQL and am trying to figure out a way by which I can check if any of the columns have a NULL value in it.

Had there been just 4 or 5 columns I could have checked them individually with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL ...
```

But is there any efficient way to do this on a lot of columns in `SQLite` specifically?

I have referred to other questions regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079037/how-to-count-in-sql-all-fields-with-null-values-in-one-record) but I cannot use xml or store anything. Also I am using `SQLite` and can only run a query.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way (that I know of) to check all columns if they contain `null` without explicitly listing all the column names.

Your query is the proper way to do it.

If you want to shorten (not significantly) the code you could use these alternatives:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE col1 + col2 + col3 IS NULL;
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE col1 || col2 || col3 IS NULL;
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE MAX(col1, col2, col3) IS NULL;
```

The above queries work, for any data type of the columns, because if there is even only 1 column equal to `null` then addition, concatenation and the scalar function `MAX()` (and `MIN()`) all return `null`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=ec3125d89e9236279853823e263860f6).

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

`PRAGMA table_info(Table_Name);`

This will return information about the columns in your table, including whether they allow `NULL` values. Look for the not-null column in the result. If it has a value of 0 for any column, it means that column allows `NULL` values. If it has a value of 1 for all columns, it means that none of the columns allow `NULL` values.